# Position button inside alert with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-position

For last few hours I've tried every possible way that came to my mind and was found on SO to move a button inside `<div>` with `alert` class to the right without changing it's vertical position, so it stays aligned with text, but unfortunately I came up with nothing.

Here is fiddle with bare html part:
https://jsfiddle.net/me420sky/

What I want is to put button on the right side. Yes, I know `pull-right` but it takes it out of regular flow and text is not aligned any more. Same goes with positioning as then page is not responsive any more.

Please can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will work.

You could remove the `line-height` property of the `span` if it doesn't matter that the text isn't vertically aligned with the button.

```css
.alert .btn-danger {
  float: right;
}

.alert span {
  line-height: 34px;
}

.alert > div:after {
  clear: both;
  content: '';
  display: table;
}
```

[**Working Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/me420sky/2/)

**Option 2: Without fixed line height of span tag**

In this case, you are giving the parent a `line-height` instead of the text. So if you've got breaking lines, the large `line-height` has no effect on the text.

```css
.alert span {
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height:normal;
}

.alert > div {
  line-height: 34px;
}
```

Comment: amazing! so simple yet I was so far from coming up with this! thank you :)

one more thing: is there a possibility of keeping text aligned without fixed line height?

Comment: You could try option 2. You still have a fixed line-height, but it has no effect on the text.

Comment: Is it necessary to use `display: table`? If you remove that, you can add `vertical-align: middle` or `position: relative; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);` on the thing you want to vertically center.

Comment: May also be `display:block`, but it has to be `block` or `table`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `btn-xs` class of bootstrap 3.

For example :

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
     Lorem ipsum...
     <button class="btn btn-xs btn-success pull-right">
              Click                     
     </button>
</div>
```

Result will be like as below:
[image]

Comment: @ambe5960 yes, but you don't use custom css in this way